# Recharts stack bar charts radius issue

Tags: recharts

Currently, with stacked bar charts, if we give the first bar a radius:
-Ex

stacked bar with upper border radius given to first bar image

[image: stacked bar with upper border radius given to first bar image]

there's the white space gaps at the upper corners of the bars, not filled in with the fill color of the bar stacked above.

I know that with the background prop, we can fill in these corners:

stacked bar with background fill image

[image: stacked bar with background fill image]

but I don't think I could get it to have the dynamic value heights.

Any help/alternatives would be appreciated!