# Recharts Stacked BarChart: Can't overlap rounded bar

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I need a stacked bar chart, whose bars have rounded edges and appear to be on top of each other. My only issue is to overlap the bars somehow, or to add a background with the color of the next bar.

[What I am expecting to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwm7l.png)

[Example of I did so far (the red is the bg fill)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwC65.png)

There is a similar issue here: [Recharts stack bar charts radius issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359782/recharts-stack-bar-charts-radius-issue) but it is not solved.

Codesandbox with a reproduction of what I did so far https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-wildflower-yvdlkw?file=/src/App.js